# Java Sets - get the type of contained items

Tags: java

I get a set of elements passed to my method without the type specified.

I want to find out what the class of the contained elements is... I know they're all of the same type.

Tried:

```
Class c = set.getClass.getComponentClass();
```

But that probably doesnt work because it's just for Array collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set set = *method argument*;
Iterator iter = set.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   Object object = iter.next();
   System.out.println(object.getClass());
}
```

Iterate over the elements in the set and print the class type, if you must. A set is a collection of elements.

Comment: Thank you, works great. Other answers were helpful aswell. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
Set<T> s
```

you can't get `T` because of type erasure.  You might be able to get it for particular implementations like `EnumSet` but in general it is not possible.

You can't even infer it from the content.  What is the type bottom of an empty set, or a set containing only null?  Even if you don't have to worry about that case, the best you can do would be to compute a type `T2 extends T` by looking at the current contents and that would be ambiguous : there may be an interface type bottom and an abstract base class -- which should you use.

The best solution would be to create a type wrapper `TypedSet<T> implements Set<T>` that takes a `Class<T>` when created.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to do this directly. What you really want are "reified generics", which don't exist in Java (yet). Java performs type erasure on generics so in general type parameters are not known at runtime.

You can iterate over the collection, and call `getClass()` on each element, and that way, find the narrowest concrete type that can accommodate every element. But, this doesn't seem very useful, as you could easily miss the fact that a lot of elements whose nearest common ancestor is `java.lang.Object` all implement the same interface, for example.

Perhaps this is an ["XY Problem".](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

get one of the objects and call getClass() on it.

Comment: Will not work if there are no objects, the object is `null`, if the type parameter is not concrete, or if the object is a subclass and there are other objects that are not subclasses of that value.  Consider a `TreeSets<CharSequence>` with an appropriate comparator that contains `("foo", new StringBuilder("bar"))`.

Comment: he said that all objects have the same type - so there are no subclasses and other objects that are no subclasses and things like that. also, he wants the type of the CONTAINED elements. so if there are no elements, the whole question makes no senes. he don't ask at the type of the set - he ask for the type of the CONTAINED elemtns. that's what i'm giving hime.

Comment: `"foo"` and `new StringBuilder("bar")` are of the same type just not of the same **concrete type**.  A `Set<CharSequence>`, `Set<Object>`, `Set<Serializable>`, `Set<Cloneable>` will all hold them just fine.  Which one would you return when they are of the same type but not the same concrete type?

Comment: i would return the most special type (so object in this case), because i can't return different types in a function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generics have other name "erasures". This second name shows clearly that generics exist in source code only and are removed by compiler. So, the information about component class of any collection (including sets) is simply removed by compiler and is not available in byte code. This is why you cannot get the type of collection component by examining collection itself. 
The only thing you can do is to get one (first) element of set and call its `getClass()`.

This patch will work for non empty collections only and will return correct results when collections contains only elements of the same type.